# Reputation split across answers

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I came across a very weird scenario today. It happened when I was about to hit the reputation cap limit of 200(only upvotes, as I've a few accepts as well) per day. For some reason, when the last `10` reputation from an upvote was to be added, it was split across 2 different upvotes on two different answers, answered around 1 min apart from each other.

To make myself more clear, here is the snapshot.

[image: Reputation split]

I've manually highlighted the 2 upvotes in discussion, where the reputation was split. Can anybody say what happened here, as I'm totally puzzled and have no clue about it? Is it a bug or a known behavior(though I've not come across it before)?

Comment: See [your reputation sorted by time](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2024761/r-j?tab=reputation&sort=time)

Comment: If I sort by time, even then I can see the reputation split where *How to remove the last separator in toString() gets 28* and the *Why does this output wrong (get/set methods) gets the rest 2*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You got several downvotes during the day.

If you:

1. hit the cap
2. got 4 downvotes to put you -8 below the cap
3. got another upvote, you get +8 to hit the cap again
4. got *another* downvote, putting you -2 below the cap
5. got *another* upvote, you hit the cap again with +2

then that explains *exactly* the pattern you see.

Then again, when you hit the rep cap and there are downvotes being undone, or posts deleted, the reputation log *can* get a little confused. You can trigger a reputation recalc once a day at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation if this bothers you, but this has always righted itself for me the next day.

In this case, I strongly suspect that the downvote at step 4 was undone within the grace period, removed from your reputation log, but the `+2` upvote of step 5 was not corrected to list as `+0` (or blank) instead. Your reputation for the day, ignoring accepts, is +200 exactly, supporting this theory; it is a text entry only, not actual reputation, and things will right themselves either automatically by tomorrow, or a reputation recalc will clear the confusing entry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation will show the votes in time order

Comment: Ah! Now I can see what happened. Thanks for your super quick answer! :)

Comment: But wait, I tried to sort the reputation on time and even then I can see a break, where *How to remove the last separator in toString() gets 28* and the *Why does this output wrong (get/set methods) gets the rest 2*.

Comment: @R.J: As I stated, sometimes the rep page *does* get it wrong, but in complex situations it is hard to tell what is going on. Take a look at the `/reputation` list to check exactly what is being listed for up and downvotes, and if that doesn't match your rep log in your profile, you can recalculate. So far, in my experience, things right themselves within 24 hours *anyway*.

Comment: Okay, I'll wait for sometime(around a day) and may be, if it doesn't get alright, I'll do a *rep recalc* and recheck. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @R.J: NP. In this case, there *is* a discrepancy, you got an extra +2 in the log for an upvote after the `+8` without an intervening `-2`. I *think* that a downvote, since undone, was in between and that confused matters here. The undone downvote would be removed from the log, your reputation would be correct, but the `+2` upvote was not corrected to `+0`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - But there is no extra *+2 rep* which I got. Without the *accepts*, the total rep from upvotes + downvotes is exactly *200* only.

Comment: @R.J: Right, so the `+2` is a phantom entry, which only strengthens my theory that it was for a downvote since undone.

Comment: Tomorrow is the day, I'll take this back into my hands and see if SO gets its stuff alright by then. Your insights were really helpful. I never knew that SO adds such phantom entries just to counter some downvote and it being revoked within the grace period.

Comment: @R.J: The stray `+2` is now gone from your rep log for yesterday. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Yeah just noticed that! :) Such a relief. Hehe. Btw, any idea why such things happen? Because I saw you mention that it happens to you also, so isn't this a bug or something of sorts?!

Comment: I already speculated in my answer why this could be: a downvote undone after another upvote gave you +2. I think that that is an edgecase not worth fixing though.